# Autoregressive Process to Moving Average Representation

Tags: autoregressive, moving-average

Suppose that we have an autoregressive process with order 1:
$$y_t = a + {\alpha}y_{t-1}+u_t$$ for $t>k$, where $k$ is a positive integer and $\alpha \in (0,1)$. And, $$y_t = b + {\alpha}y_{t-1}+u_t$$ for $t\leq k$. And assume that $a$ and $b$ are two different real constants. $u_t$ are iid with mean $0$ and a variance, $\sigma$ constant and finite.

Now, I am trying to get the moving average of the infinity order process of this.
Normally, $\alpha$ being in the interval $(0,1)$, implies that ${\sup}_t \ E(y_t)$ is finite. Thus, the space of sequences of $y_t$s is Banach space and we proceed with geometric series sum.

In this case, do we have to still show that ${\sup}_t \ E(y_t)$ is finite? Or, $\alpha$ being in the interval $(0,1)$ implies this?